# cli command to run keyboard shortcuts, e.g. Alt-F2?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, cinnamon

I want to use hot corner for run dialog window. What is the name and command of that tiny box (program) which is called when I press Alt-F2? This is cinnamon related question.

For example, under lxde, keybinding for that dialog box is Alt+F2 and it executes >lxpanelctl run< command..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Run xdotool commands to simulate key strokes instead

Not literally what you asked for, but nevertheless a solution would be to use `xdotool` to simulate keystrokes / key combinations, and achieve the same result.

If you add these commands to hot corners, you will achieve exactly what you describe.

#### How to do that

1. Install `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Simulate the keystrokes you'd like to use. From your example: the command

   ```
   xdotool key Alt+F2
   ```

   does the same as actually pressing those keys. That way you won't need to know the actual commands "under the hood". As terdon mentions, those actions will most likely not be available as separate commands.

See also [man xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/xdotool.1.html) or [this link](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#keyboard_commands)

Comment: That's it. Thank You very much.  The exact command is 'xdotool key Alt+F2'

Comment: @folti7 Of course, `xdotool key Alt+F2` is better, while `xdotool key alt key F2` works, but less elegant :) I edited your suggestion into my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

That is almost certainly not a dedicated program but just a part of Unity. I know this is the case for Cinnamon for example.

As an alternative, you can set the hot corner to launch a terminal. That's basically the same thing except that you'll have to close the terminal manually.

---

In the specific case of cinnamon, what is run is a javascript script. Cinnamon runs a lot of javascript under the hood. That is not something you can run yourself, however, it is being interpreted by cinnamon itself and is not an external program. Specifically, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> will run `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/runDialog.js` but I don't think it will be possible to run that manually.

Comment: Thank you :) That's the plan B I'm also using Cinnamon, but would really like to know what exact command invokes that dialog box whe we press Alt+F2.  You know when something is just bugging you... :D anyhow, thanks for reply.

Comment: @folti7 if your question is about cinnamon, please edit it and make that clear. I added the name of the specific script cinnamon runs but, as I said, I don't think you'll be able to launch this from the hot corner.